# What is the syntax for new line in Objective-C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Can anyone tell me what is the symbol used for new line?

In the C language we use `'\n'` for new line. What do we use in Objective-C?

is it same?

Comment: It is the same. Please refer [this link][1] for more detail. [1]:http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Objective-C_2.0_Data_Types#Special_Characters.2FEscape_Sequences

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Objective-C is an extension of C. So '\n' works too in Objective-C.

Answer (score 15):

It's the same (`\n`), but there's a lot more to the topic depending on whether it's just a new *line* or a new *paragraph*, what context the text will be processed in, etc. From [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/stringsParagraphBreaks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005016-SW1) (referencing the Cocoa docs here because they cover both Objective-C [implicitly] and Cocoa, since you have the `iphone` tag on your question):

> There are a number of ways in which a line or paragraph break may be represented. Historically `\n`, `\r`, and `\r\n` have been used. Unicode defines an unambiguous paragraph separator, `U+2029` (for which Cocoa provides the constant `NSParagraphSeparatorCharacter`), and an unambiguous line separator, `U+2028` (for which Cocoa provides the constant `NSLineSeparatorCharacter`).
>
> In the Cocoa text system, the `NSParagraphSeparatorCharacter` is treated consistently as a paragraph break, and `NSLineSeparatorCharacter` is treated consistently as a line break that is not a paragraph break—that is, a line break within a paragraph. However, in other contexts, there are few guarantees as to how these characters will be treated. POSIX-level software, for example, often recognizes only `\n` as a break. Some older Macintosh software recognizes only `\r`, and some Windows software recognizes only `\r\n`. Often there is no distinction between line and paragraph breaks.
>
> Which line or paragraph break character you should use depends on how your data may be used and on what platforms. The Cocoa text system recognizes `\n`, `\r`, or `\r\n` all as paragraph breaks—equivalent to `NSParagraphSeparatorCharacter`. When it inserts paragraph breaks, for example with `insertNewline`:, it uses `\n`. Ordinarily `NSLineSeparatorCharacter` is used only for breaks that are specifically line breaks and not paragraph breaks, for example in `insertLineBreak`:, or for representing HTML `<br>` elements.
>
> If your breaks are specifically intended as line breaks and not paragraph breaks, then you should typically use `NSLineSeparatorCharacter`. Otherwise, you may use `\n`, `\r`, or `\r\n` depending on what other software is likely to process your text. The default choice for Cocoa is usually `\n`.

Comment: Do you know the character that NSLineSeparatorCharacter represents?

Comment: @vakio: Yes, it's in the quote above: U+2028, that is, Unicode code point 2028, the "unambiguous" line separator character.

Comment: Oh, thanks. I missed it. I was looking for a \l or something.

Comment: What should I include so I can use NSParagraphSeparatorCharacter

Comment: Sorry - but I cannot find NSLineSeparatorCharacter anywhere in iOS SDK 12, or in Xcode documentation. Which header declares this constant?

Comment: @MottiShneor - According to Apple, it's a global variable: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nslineseparatorcharacter It's equivalent to 0x2028 (the Unicode line separator character), and `NSParagraphSeparatorCharacter` is equivalent to 0x2029 (the Unicode paragraph separator).

Answer (score 2):

It's the same, but if you are printing to the console, you should use

```
NSLog(@"This is a console statement\n on two different lines");
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

It's same dude. Objective-c is superset of c so most of the things from c will work in objective-c too.

Answer (score 0):

Its same.In Objective c "\n" use for new line.