# Where is NSLineSeparatorCharacter defined?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, constants, newline

I've been Googling, grepping and searching high and low, but can't find the answer. Which header file do I need to include to get the definitions of these constants in **iOS**?

```
NSLineSeparatorCharacter
NSNewLineCharacter
NSParagraphSeparatorCharacter
```

Comment: I've tried using all three of them.  I get compile errors:  `error: use of undeclared identifier 'NSLineSeparatorCharacter'
error: use of undeclared identifier 'NSNewLineCharacter'
error: use of undeclared identifier 'NSParagraphSeparatorCharacter'`

Comment: @user125697 yeah, I read that. Actually, that question is how I learned that these constants are supposed to exist. Unfortunately it gives me no clue as to where those contants are defined, and neither does the linked Apple documentation on line and paragraph endings

Comment: You read this too right? http://stackoverflow.com/a/6420494/1586880

Comment: @user125697 yep, read that too.  Did you see the comment someone else posted in that question? It reads "What should I include so I can use NSParagraphSeparatorCharacter"

Comment: So why can't you just hardcode them? Say if you need NSNewLineCharacter you'd use \n for example? or am I missing something

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those constants are defined in `NSText.h` which is only for OS X, not iOS. Therefore you can't use those constants in iOS.

`NSLineSeparatorCharacter` is defined as: `0x2028`

`NSNewLineCharacter` is defined as: `0x000a`

`NSParagraphSeparatorCharacter` is defined as: `0x2029`

Answer (score 0):

In Swift, this can be defined as:

```
let NSNewLineCharacter = "\u{000a}"
let NSLineSeparatorCharacter = "\u{2028}"
let NSParagraphSeparatorCharacter = "\u{2029}"
```